# Unexpected Python Hash Truncation

Tags: python, hash, truncation

I have a custom `__hash__` function.

I'm aware that `hash(object)` truncates to the specified integer width. That's 64 on my system.

However, if `& 0xffffffffffffffff` the value that gets kicked out of my custom hash function, it's sometimes (but not always!) being mutated by the truncation.

What's going on?

Comment: mutated how? any example?

Answer (score 1):

Python hashes are *signed* integers. Your `__hash__` output might fit in an unsigned 64-bit int, but not necessarily a signed one. (Also, that's not truncation you're seeing.)